# How to disable internet access to an app installed in an alpine based docker image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I have the below Dockerfile based on alpine image.

As you can see I'm installing chromium to print pdfs.

I would like to disallow internet access to chromium for security reason and because I'm using local (in app) html files that do not require internet access to be opened.

Is this possible?

```
FROM alpine:3

RUN apk upgrade --no-cache --available && apk add --no-cache chromium

# How to disable internet access to chromium here?

COPY /app/ .

CMD app
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable all sorts of internet connections to the outside world, you can simply set the container network to `none`.
`docker run --network none <you options> <your image>`.
[More info on setting container network to none](https://docs.docker.com/network/none/#:%7E:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20completely,the%20loopback%20device%20is%20created.)

But if there are some specific addresses that you want to prevent chromium from accessing, you can add them to container hosts and map them to a wrong ip like 127.0.0.1.
[More info on using `--add-host`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/)

It's possible to use these options in a docker-compose file also if you're using one.

Comment: I'm talking about app inside docker container. I'm not running the container myself.

Comment: I think setting a wrong https_proxy would help.